# DB normalization and subqueries

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I'm taking a course on databases and I have a couple of questions about computational problems. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

First, I hear it thrown around that there "is no algorithm" to convert relations to BCNF which is both lossless and dependency preserving. The reason for this is that, for some relations, there does not exist a relation in BCNF with the desired properties. I find this misleading, in the sense that you could say there's no algorithm to find two real solutions of a quadratic equation using the same logic. Sure you can't... But for the normalization problem, I think it should be possible to determine whether there is a transformation to BCNF with both properties (decision problem) and, if the decision problem emits "yes", an algorithm to compute an equivalent BCNF representation. Is my thinking right, or is any of what I have said wrong?

My second question regards subqueries. Can any query in SQL involving subqueries be rewritten without subqueries? I know this isn't very well-formulated... I guess let's stick to basic SQL (what most/all systems share) and limit subqueries to select statements subordinate to a top-level one (allowing for top-level set operations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - As far as I know, there is not any single algorithm to determine whether the relation can be converted to BCNF while preserving its properties. However, you can combine existing ones too achieve what you want.

Using relation decomposition algorithms, you can decompose your relation and then check its dependencies. If its dependency preserving you have your result, otherwise you can backtrace your steps and return the original state of relation.

I know its not the answer you want but can be used as a solution.

2 - If you mean nested queries, yes some queries involving subqueries can be written without using subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for this. For the first one, I'm thinking there is a finite number of distinct, meaningful decompositions... So an algorithm would be to generate them all and check them. For the second... We agree that there are some queries where you can eliminate subqueries. Are there some things you can only do with subqueries, though?